# Unable to send message on SQS through AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am not able to send message on an SQS queue through AWS Java SDK. Here is code that I am using:

```
    final AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    try {
        String queueUrl = "My sqs queue url"
        sqs.sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest(queueUrl, "This is my message text."));
    } catch (final AmazonServiceException ase) {
        //log error message here                
    } catch (final AmazonClientException ace) {
        //log error message here
    }
```

This snippet throws `AmazonServiceException` with message:    **The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details**

In SDK documentation, there is nothing mentioned about how to sign the request. 
Also, For authentication, I have exported environment variables  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY containing AWS access key and secret values.

I picked this sample code from [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html)

Can anyone help me about how to fix this?

Comment: try to specify the region as well AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

Comment: @gusto2, I just tried specifying the region, but it did not help.

Comment: Which version of the SDK do you use? Are you sure the credentials passed to the SQS client are those you expect (*i.e* they are not overwritten somewhere)? In which region is your SQS queue? (the default region is `us-west-2`)

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with my credentials. Things started working when I tried creating a new account and used fresh pair of key and secret. 
I will ask my AWS account manager of my organization to regenerate the key-secrete pair.
Thanks @gusto2 and @AlexandreDupriez.